# How to select certificate when I make a profile with push notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Now I develop a app with push notification and I make files followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

and at the step:Making the Provisioning Profile->Step 3: Generate, I want to generate a development provisioning profile, but I didn't find any APNS development IOS certificate that I created on Certificate category. and why ?  and I find that in the select box that the certificate type is ios development, why? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: i followed same tut. where exactly u are facing issue? i'm not getting it ?

Comment: in category APP ID , I created a  ssl development certificate with ANPS DEVELOPMENT ISO type, and then I find it in the category CERTIFICATES, then I want to create the development provisioning profile for develop on my phone, but when I take the step 3 , I didn't find any ANPS CERTIFICATE I have created. just like other development type certificates in the apple account, and in old apple developer, I thought this is auto check for me , but the new version , I didn't find the right certificate? why ? thank you very much!!!